# Not passing **kwargs to django-import-export resources from custom view/form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-import-export

When I use this resources.py inside Django admin everything works fine. However, when I do it on my custom view page there is an issue that popped with the **kwargs user auto-populate.

The error must be in my view as it's not passing the **kwargs but I'm not sure how to solve it. Where should I be passing this information?

```
KeyError at /import/
'user'

C:\Users\winkl\tj3\venv\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py in import_row
            self.after_import_instance(instance, new, **kwargs) …

C:\Users\winkl\tj3\portfolios\resources.py in after_import_instance
        instance.created_by = kwargs['user']
```

resources.py

```
class EntryResource(resources.ModelResource):

    symbol = fields.Field(
    attribute="symbol",
    column_name="symbol",
    widget=SymbolWidget(Symbol, 'name'),
    )

    date = fields.Field(
    attribute="date",
    column_name="date",
    widget=widgets.DateTimeWidget(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('symbol', 'date', 'id', 'amount', 'price', 'fee', 'entry_type', 'reg_fee',)
        import_order = fields
        skip_unchanged = False
        report_skipped = True

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        print(f' Kwargs: {kwargs}')
        instance.created_by = kwargs['user']

    def after_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        pass
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def import_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        trade_resource = EntryResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_trades = request.FILES['importData']

        imported_data = dataset.load(new_trades.read().decode('utf-8'),format='csv')
        result = trade_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)

        if result.has_errors():
            messages.error(request, 'Uh oh! Something went wrong...')

        else:
            # Import now
            trade_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)
            messages.success(request, 'Your words were successfully imported')

    return render(request, 'dashboard/import.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you are getting the error because there is no entry with key 'user' in the kwargs dict.

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L709), you can see that the `kwargs` get passed down the call stack into `after_import_instance()`.

In your case, at no point is there ever a `user` entry in the kwargs dict.

However, if you pass this value in to the `import_data()` call then it can be retrieved and used:

```py
 your_user = load_user() # implement this as required
 result = trade_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True, user=your_user)
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Was not sure where to pass that data. I just made your_user = request.user and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What would be the best way to set up a non-admin review page for the imports?

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app), and copy how it's done for the example admin site in your app.